# click() not working on difficult to navigate website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm fairly new to Python and very new to Selenium.  I want to click on a button on a website that has no class or id attributes.

I've tried using XPath with `find_element_by_xpath()` and `click()` but either doesn't seem to do anything or just generates an error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from config import my_user, my_password


browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.set_window_size(1600, 1200)
browser.set_window_position(0, 0)
browser.get('http://thefutoncritic.com/myfuton/listings/')

email_box = browser.find_element_by_name('email')
email_box.send_keys(my_user)
password_box = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password_box.send_keys(my_password)
password_box.submit()

listings_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[6]/div/a')
listings_button.click()
```

Excerpt from website:

```
<tbody><tr height="37">
...
<td width="150">
<div style="width:150; height=37; background-image:url('/images/my-listings.jpg'); background-position:0 -37px;">
<a href="/myfuton/listings/"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" width="150" height="37" border="0">
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tspgallagher/Projects/Python/Sandbox/temp2.py", line 17, in <module>
    listings_button.click()
  File "/Users/tspgallagher/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/tspgallagher/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/tspgallagher/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/tspgallagher/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

Comment: I've been trying to answer you, but my formatting skills are sadly lacking in this forum.  Short answer is no, it did not work.  I'm not sure if the issue is it can't follow the XPATH to use click() method or not.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'find_element'

Comment: [ tspgallagher iMac ~/Projects/Python/Sandbox ] pip3 list | grep selenium
selenium          3.141.0

Answer (score 0):

Please check below solution with waitt and relative xpath

```
driver.get("http://thefutoncritic.com/myfuton/listings/")


element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[4]//tbody[1]//tr[1]//td[6]//div[1]//a[1]//img[1]")))
element.click()
element0=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text(),'Welcome to MYFUTON, our new - and completely free')]")))

print(element0.text)
#     print(elements)
# driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='bubble-element GroupItem group-item entry-1']//button[@class='fa fa-spotify inner-element bubble-element clickable-element']").click()
print driver.current_url
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/myfuton/listings/')]")
```

**EDIT**

Using wait for element clickable from expected conditions could do the trick, or at least give you an indication where the problem might be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, '/myfuton/listings/')]")))

element.click();
```

This is assuming it takes a while for the element to be clickable. It might not be the case. Perhaps the element is obscured by a pop-up, or something like that. In that case what you can do is you can simulate a click on an element directly BEFORE that link and then simulate pressing the TAB key, and then ENTER.

Comment: click() method failed

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: